# add more servlet in undertow to servlet builder

Tags: java, servlets, undertow

I have this code that add servlet, and the url

```
        DeploymentInfo servletBuilder = deployment()
                .setClassLoader(ServletServer.class.getClassLoader())
                .setContextPath(MYAPP)
                .setDeploymentName("test.war")
                .addServlets(
                        servlet("MyServlet", MessageServlet.class)
                        .addInitParam("message", "My own Servlet")
                        .addMapping("/myservlet"));

        DeploymentManager manager = defaultContainer().addDeployment(servletBuilder);
        manager.deploy();

        HttpHandler servletHandler = manager.start();
        PathHandler path = Handlers.path(Handlers.redirect(MYAPP))
                .addPrefixPath(MYAPP, servletHandler);
        Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
                .addHttpListener(8080, "localhost")
                .setHandler(path)
                .build();
        server.start();
```

However, I have tried to use this version but its not working

```
I have this code that add servlet, and the url

.addServlets(servlet("MyServlet", MessageServlet.class)
  .addInitParam("message", "My own Servlet")
  .addMapping("/myservlet"));
```

This doesn't work because the latter servlet(url) part was working while the former didn't . I mean myservlet1 was working while myservlet wasn't working anymore

Comment: Please, tidy up your code in post a bit.

Comment: After tidying up this code, no body could give me the answer?
Is it that undertow is so poorly documented that simple thing like this is missing out in the doc?

Comment: how do I mark a question as duplicate and what number of reputation is required

Comment: @olyjosh I already marked this question as duplicate, see the banner on top and on the bottom of this post.